# Return value of the overridden attribute accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I just found that, when I override the boolean setter of a Rails model, the return value behaves unexpectedly.

Here is a simple `User` model where `is_admin` is a boolean field. What I want is pretty straightforward: cast `String` `'T'`, `'F'` into `true`, `false` respectively.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def is_admin=(value)
    case value
    when 'T'
      super(true)
    when 'F'
      super(false)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

The cast works fine. `u = User.new; u.is_admin = 'T'` does set `u.is_admin` to `true`. However the expression

```
u.is_admin = 'T'
```

returns `'T'` rather than `true`.

This is easily reproduced by creating a brand new Rails 5 project and create a model named `User` with only one column `is_admin` as `boolean`. After that, override `:is_admin` as I did, you will see what I saw.

Any idea on the weird return value? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment operator always returns the right hand value. Simple as that. Observe:

```
class Foo
  def bar=(val)
    @bar = val.to_s # => "1234"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 1234 # => 1234
```

Comment: Yes this is what I believe. But in my case this is not true. Without overriding the return value of the setter is normal. But not with a overridden version calling super here. It's not hard to reproduce the error. You can follow what I left in the question.

Comment: @Xenofex: "without the overridding" you're assigning booleans, right? And it returns booleans, as there's no casting, right? So how do you decide if this return value is from the setter or the assignment operator itself?

Comment: Hi, @Sergio Tulentsev, after reading your answer again I think I see what you are saying here. Even if my overriding looks like the a method, it is different - it's an assignment operator which always returns the right hand value instead of the 'last line' (or even I give an explicit return value). Thanks for the explanation. Though is there a doc or a reference about this?

Comment: @Xenofex: cursory googling didn't reveal a link to official documentation. Although there must be one somewhere :)